# ID generated for a field where ID should not be generated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following a tutorial on `MERN stack`, we have created a route to add experience of user

When I add anything to the experience field using postman,an additional id field is being generated. **How is id being generated ???**. If experience was a different schema and I had linked it to the profile schema then id could have been generated but in this case I see no reason for it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbmUd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wWn8.png)

profile schema

```
 const mongoose=require('mongoose')

 const ProfileSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
},
company: {
    type: String
},
website: {
    type: String
},
location: {
    type: String
},
status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
},
bio: {
    type: String
},
githubusername: {
    type: String
},
experience: [
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            type: String
        },
        from: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        to: {
            type: Date
        },
        current: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        }
    }
],
education: [
    {
        school: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        degree: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        fieldofstudy: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        from: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        to: {
            type: Date
        },
        current: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        }
    }
],
social: {
    youtube: {
        type: String
    },
    twitter: {
        type: String
    },
    facebook: {
        type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
        type: String
    },
    instagram: {
        type: String
    }
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
})


module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

the route to add experience

```
router.put('/experience',[auth,[
check('title',"title is required").not().isEmpty(),
check('company', "company is required").not().isEmpty(),
check('from', "from date is required").not().isEmpty()
 ] ],async(req,res)=>{
const errors=validationResult(req)
if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    return res.status(400).json({errors:errors.array()})
}
const {
    title,company,location,from,to,current,description
}=req.body

const newExp={
    title,company,location,from,to,current,description
}
try{
    const profile=await Profile.findOne({user:req.user.id})
    profile.experience.unshift(newExp)
    await profile.save()
    res.json(profile)

}catch(e){
    console.log(e.message)
    res.status(500).send('server error')
}
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_id` field is generated by MongoDb, also it creates index for it automatically and use this for making any CRUD operation on the documents.
You can check [MongoDb Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/) and [Id field](https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/what-is-mongodbs-id-field-and-how-to-use-it).